# jQuery Script in External .js file not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a small piece of script in an external .js file that will not run. Here is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#chkAllTracts').change(function () {
        alert("fired");
    })
});
```

I have a number of other functions in the same .js file that use some jQuery and they all work fine but this is the first jQuery I have attempted to use inside this syntax:

```
$(document).ready(function (){   }
```

All I am trying to do is make an alert open when a checkbox is changed (checked or unchecked). The checkbox element "chkAllTracts" is added dynamically using jQuery before this function is called.

Comment: You could simplify it to `$(function() {...});`.  That always works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#checkbox1').mousedown(function() {
    if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
        alert("test")
    }
});
```

something like that? (edited)

Comment: @imbask - Thank you for your response. I should have been more clear in my question. The mousedown option will not work for me because the checkbox will not always be clicked. Sometimes the checked/unchecked state will occur programmatically. But, thanks again for taking the time to assist me, I appreciate your consideration!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("body").append( 
    $("<input>")
      .attr("type", "checkbox")
      .change(function(){ alert("It works!"); }))
});
```

When the document is ready it includes in the body the checkbox input with the change event set to fire the alert message.

Answer (score 0):

It is because your element is dynamically added to the DOM. jQuery selectors would not get hold of it when jQuery first initialise. What you need to do is

```
$('body').find('#chkAllTracts').change(function () {
    alert("fired");
});
```

I think that should solve your problem.